# How to display and save the M values of the big-M transformation in Pyomo?

Tags: python, pyomo

I'm learning how to use the Pyomo GDP package and I would like to know if there is a way to visualise and store the M values of the Big-M transformation. I am solving the problem *A mixing problem with semi-continuous variables* from the Pyomo book.

```
# scont.py
import pyomo.environ as pyo 
from pyomo.gdp import Disjunct, Disjunction

L = [1,2,3]
U = [2,4,6]
index = [0,1,2]

model = pyo.ConcreteModel() 
model.x = pyo.Var(index, within=pyo.Reals, bounds=(0,20))
model.x_nonzero = pyo.Var(index, bounds=(0,1))

# Each disjunct is a semi-continuous variable
# x[k] == 0 or L[k] <= x[k] <= U[k]


def d_0_rule(d, k):
    m = d.model()
    d.c = pyo.Constraint(expr=m.x[k] == 0)

model.d_0 = Disjunct(index, rule=d_0_rule)

def d_nonzero_rule(d, k):
    m = d.model()
    d.c = pyo.Constraint(expr=pyo.inequality(L[k], m.x[k], U[k]))
    d.count = pyo.Constraint(expr=m.x_nonzero[k] == 1)
model.d_nonzero = Disjunct(index, rule=d_nonzero_rule)

def D_rule(m, k):
    return[m.d_0[k], m.d_nonzero[k]]
model.D = Disjunction(index, rule=D_rule)

# Minimize the number of x variables that are nonzero

model.o = pyo.Objective(expr=sum(model.x_nonzero[k] for k in index))

# Satisfy a demand that is met by these variables
                    
model.c = pyo.Constraint(expr=sum(model.x[k]for k in index) >= 7)

xfrm = pyo.TransformationFactory('gdp.bigm')
xfrm.apply_to(model)

solver = pyo.SolverFactory('gurobi')
status = solver.solve(model)
model.display()
```

When I visualise the solution, it looks like this

```
enter code  Variables:
x : Size=3, Index=x_index
    Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
      0 :     0 :   0.0 :    20 : False : False :  Reals
      1 :     0 :   4.0 :    20 : False : False :  Reals
      2 :     0 :   6.0 :    20 : False : False :  Reals
x_nonzero : Size=3, Index=x_nonzero_index
    Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
      0 :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False :  Reals
      1 :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False :  Reals
      2 :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False :  Reals

  Objectives:
    o : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Active : Value
        None :   True :   2.0

  Constraints:
    c : Size=1
    Key  : Lower : Body : Upper
    None :   7.0 : 10.0 :  None

  Blocks:
Block _pyomo_gdp_bigm_reformulation

  Variables:
    None

  Objectives:
    None

  Constraints:
    D_xor : Size=3
        Key : Lower : Body : Upper
          0 :   1.0 :  1.0 :   1.0
          1 :   1.0 :  1.0 :   1.0
          2 :   1.0 :  1.0 :   1.0

  Blocks:
    Block _pyomo_gdp_bigm_reformulation.relaxedDisjuncts[0]
    
      Variables:
        None
    
      Objectives:
        None
    
      Constraints:
        d_0[0].c : Size=2
            Key : Lower : Body : Upper
             lb :   0.0 :  0.0 :  None
             ub :  None :  0.0 :   0.0
    
      Blocks:
        Block _pyomo_gdp_bigm_reformulation.relaxedDisjuncts[0].localVarReferences
        
          Variables:
            d_0[0].binary_indicator_var : Size=1, Index=_pyomo_gdp_bigm_reformulation.relaxedDisjuncts[0].localVarReferences.'d_0[0].binary_indicator_var_index', ReferenceTo=d_0[0].binary_indicator_var
                Key  : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
                None :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        
          Objectives:
            None
        
          Constraints:
            None
    Block _pyomo_gdp_bigm_reformulation.relaxedDisjuncts[1]
    
      Variables:
        None
    
      Objectives:
        None
    
      Constraints:
        d_nonzero[0].c : Size=2
            Key : Lower : Body  : Upper
             lb :   1.0 :   1.0 :  None
             ub :  None : -18.0 :   2.0
        d_nonzero[0].count : Size=2
            Key : Lower : Body : Upper
             lb :   1.0 :  1.0 :  None
             ub :  None :  0.0 :   1.0
    
      Blocks:
        Block _pyomo_gdp_bigm_reformulation.relaxedDisjuncts[1].localVarReferences
        
          Variables:
            d_nonzero[0].binary_indicator_var : Size=1, Index=_pyomo_gdp_bigm_reformulation.relaxedDisjuncts[1].localVarReferences.'d_nonzero[0].binary_indicator_var_index', ReferenceTo=d_nonzero[0].binary_indicator_var
                Key  : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
                None :     0 :  -0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        
          Objectives:
            None
        
          Constraints:
            None
    Block _pyomo_gdp_bigm_reformulation.relaxedDisjuncts[2]
    
      Variables:
        None
    
      Objectives:
        None
    
      Constraints:
        d_0[1].c : Size=2
            Key : Lower : Body  : Upper
             lb :   0.0 :   4.0 :  None
             ub :  None : -16.0 :   0.0
    
      Blocks:
        Block _pyomo_gdp_bigm_reformulation.relaxedDisjuncts[2].localVarReferences
        
          Variables:
            d_0[1].binary_indicator_var : Size=1, Index=_pyomo_gdp_bigm_reformulation.relaxedDisjuncts[2].localVarReferences.'d_0[1].binary_indicator_var_index', ReferenceTo=d_0[1].binary_indicator_var
                Key  : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
                None :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        
          Objectives:
            None
        
          Constraints:
            None
    Block _pyomo_gdp_bigm_reformulation.relaxedDisjuncts[3]
    
      Variables:
        None
    
      Objectives:
        None
    
      Constraints:
        d_nonzero[1].c : Size=2
            Key : Lower : Body : Upper
             lb :   2.0 :  4.0 :  None
             ub :  None :  4.0 :   4.0
        d_nonzero[1].count : Size=2
            Key : Lower : Body : Upper
             lb :   1.0 :  1.0 :  None
             ub :  None :  1.0 :   1.0
    
      Blocks:
        Block _pyomo_gdp_bigm_reformulation.relaxedDisjuncts[3].localVarReferences
        
          Variables:
            d_nonzero[1].binary_indicator_var : Size=1, Index=_pyomo_gdp_bigm_reformulation.relaxedDisjuncts[3].localVarReferences.'d_nonzero[1].binary_indicator_var_index', ReferenceTo=d_nonzero[1].binary_indicator_var
                Key  : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
                None :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        
          Objectives:
            None
        
          Constraints:
            None
    Block _pyomo_gdp_bigm_reformulation.relaxedDisjuncts[4]
    
      Variables:
        None
    
      Objectives:
        None
    
      Constraints:
        d_0[2].c : Size=2
            Key : Lower : Body  : Upper
             lb :   0.0 :   6.0 :  None
             ub :  None : -14.0 :   0.0
    
      Blocks:
        Block _pyomo_gdp_bigm_reformulation.relaxedDisjuncts[4].localVarReferences
        
          Variables:
            d_0[2].binary_indicator_var : Size=1, Index=_pyomo_gdp_bigm_reformulation.relaxedDisjuncts[4].localVarReferences.'d_0[2].binary_indicator_var_index', ReferenceTo=d_0[2].binary_indicator_var
                Key  : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
                None :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        
          Objectives:
            None
        
          Constraints:
            None
    Block _pyomo_gdp_bigm_reformulation.relaxedDisjuncts[5]
    
      Variables:
        None
    
      Objectives:
        None
    
      Constraints:
        d_nonzero[2].c : Size=2
            Key : Lower : Body : Upper
             lb :   3.0 :  6.0 :  None
             ub :  None :  6.0 :   6.0
        d_nonzero[2].count : Size=2
            Key : Lower : Body : Upper
             lb :   1.0 :  1.0 :  None
             ub :  None :  1.0 :   1.0
    
      Blocks:
        Block _pyomo_gdp_bigm_reformulation.relaxedDisjuncts[5].localVarReferences
        
          Variables:
            d_nonzero[2].binary_indicator_var : Size=1, Index=_pyomo_gdp_bigm_reformulation.relaxedDisjuncts[5].localVarReferences.'d_nonzero[2].binary_indicator_var_index', ReferenceTo=d_nonzero[2].binary_indicator_var
                Key  : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
                None :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        
          Objectives:
            None
        
          Constraints:
            None
```

As can be seen, it is not possible to see what value the M values have taken.
How can I visualise them?

The Multiple Big-M (MBM) Reformulation has an option to store the M values.

```
M_values = mbigm.get_all_M_values(model)
```

Is there something similar for Big-M?